# Find the exact usage of a function name in a string by re-seq re-pattern - Clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

My f function is not working as I expected. I would like to find exact matchings in the given string but my f function is working something weird:

Let me explain what I trying to do roughly, going to give a local repo path as args in a slurp function then read all of `clj`, `cljs`, and `cljc` files in the location, parse them into the string and then try to sum usage of Clojure core functions which are how many times used. I hope I explained clearly what I trying to do.

edit 1: I am going to try to implement the pure f function.
edit 2: Sorry, I organized the question like MRE.

```clj
(defn f "searchs the given value(inside !type atom) inside given text(vector-0f-texts)"
  [regex text]
  (count (re-seq (re-pattern regex) text)))


(def function-text
  "str-path  str")

(f "str" function-text)
=> 2
;expected => 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what are "exact matches" according to your definition.
Could you clarify your intent in the description? Include what you expect it to return and what it returns instead.

Comment: I'd also suggest to make `f` pure - that is pass the pattern as an argument, do not get the pattern from the `!type` atom.

Comment: i.e. "with-open" function is not used in the given string but when I  (count (re-seq (with-open) text))) then this returns me 6. but in this string, we can see there is no usage of "with-open". This must be caused by regex. It looks into a string if every char chars of "with-open"  exist then it returns me a usage. 


example:
(f "a hello m world p")   (count (re-seq (re-pattern "map") text))
it returns me a usage that's not what I looking for.  
I want just exact matches like here"
(f "hello world map")   (count (re-seq (re-pattern "map") text))
now it should return me a usage.

Comment: You really need to edit and polish your question. Moreover, what you say doesn't make sense. It might be because of that `!type` atom you are using doesn't contain the value/regex you expect. If you make `f` pure function accepting two args `[pattern text]` and run `(f "with-open" your-long-text)` then you will see it returns 0.

Comment: With a regexp you will most likely only ever find the name and not the function. You are OK with also counting `(filter (fn [map] (get map :key)) xs)` for two?

Comment: I trying but still getting some wrong results if I am not wrong. (defn f 
  [regex text]
  (count (re-seq (re-pattern regex) text)))
(f "int?" text) 
;=> 3               Why it finds 3 usages of "int?" There is no int? usages in the string that I used in the function.

Comment: Also, `re-seq` can find that regex in the docstring, comment or string- you probably don't want to count these occurrences.

Comment: yes, that will be my next target to avoid comments docstrings etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clearer, I'm posting this as an answer, not just a comment.

Given this definition:

```
(defn f "searchs the given value(inside !type atom) inside given text(vector-0f-texts)"
  [pattern text]
  (count (re-seq (re-pattern pattern) text)))
```

and using this text

```
(def function-text 
  "(defn idx->meta [pair-col]
     (->> pair-col
          (apply hash-map)
          (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
                       (let [idx       k
                             str-vals  (filterv string? (vals v))
                             str-paths (->> str-vals
                                            (map #(clojure.string/split % #\"\")))]
                         (->> str-paths
                              (reduce (fn [acc str-path]
                                        (update-in acc str-path (fnil conj []) v))
                                      acc))))
                     {})
          )
     )")
```

You can do some experiments:

```
(f "with-open" function-text)
;; => 0
(f "int?" function-text)
;; => 3
(f "int\\?" function-text)
;; => 0
```

In particular, `?` is a special character in regexes and it means "zero or one repetition" of the previous pattern.
This is nothing specific to Clojure or Java, it's a standard regex behavior.

**UPDATE: exact matching of symbols**
Exact matching might be a bit tricky, but this could work,
by excluding all the characters that are valid in Clojure symbols:

```
(defn f
  "searchs the given value(inside !type atom) inside given text(vector-0f-texts)"
  [pattern text]
  ;; See https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_symbols for valid characters in Clojure symbols
  (count (re-seq (re-pattern (str "\\Q" pattern "\\E" "[^a-zA-Z0-9*+!\\-_'?]")) text)))
```

It also uses "\Q" and "\E" to simulate `Pattern/quote` (see cfrick's comment).

Btw. for a more serious analysis, I'd look at https://github.com/clj-kondo/clj-kondo
I have some quick experiments here: https://github.com/jumarko/clojure-experiments/blob/develop/src/clojure_experiments/linters/clj_kondo.clj#L1

Comment: Thank you for answer, everything looks good, now I just need to solve that --->  (f "str" function-text)
 => 8  Is there any option just to get just exact matches? "str" must match with "str" not "str-something". Or it is impossible to do that?

Comment: If you know, you are not looking for reg-exp-chars (e.g. from user-input), you should use `(java.util.regex.Pattern/quote "?")` to eliminate that problem.

Comment: @cfrick are we talk about to eliminate "int?" problem?

Comment: That worked for me, thanks to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be quite accurate, a reg-exp will only bring you so far.
You are way better off using a parser.

For trivial tasks, you can use the core reader, e.g. `read-string`.
This has no clue, what is actually going on (e.g. is this a function
name or a let binding), but at least gives you things as what they are
(no need to deal with every word barrier out there or exclude strings).
For a naive count for some symbols, you can use something like this:

```clj
(->> (read-string s) ; `s` is from your example
     (tree-seq (some-fn list? vector? map?) seq) ; "flatten" the tree
     (filter #{'map 'acc}) ; only pick symbols with the names map or acc
     (frequencies)
     (prn))
```

And if you are quite serious about this, you might instead consider
libraries like:

- [tools.analyzer](https://github.com/clojure/tools.analyzer)
- [rewrite-clj](https://github.com/clj-commons/rewrite-clj)

This is an example using tools.analyzer:

```clj
(ns tana.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.analyzer.jvm :as ana]))

(defn ana-branch?
  "tree-seq branch? predicate for clojure.tools.analyzer.jmv/analyze"
  [node]
  (or (and (map? node) (:children node))
      (vector? node)))

(defn ana-children
  "tree-seq children extractor for clojure.tools.analyzer.jmv/analyze"
  [node]
  (if (map? node)
    (map node (:children node))
    (seq node)))

(defn ana-tree-seq
  "Create a tree-seq over the result from clojure.tools.analyzer.jmv/analyze"
  [root]
  (tree-seq ana-branch? ana-children root))

(defn ana-var=-fn
  "Creates a predicate function to check, if the given node is a :var :op and the symbol of :var is the given sym"
  [sym]
  (fn [node]
    (and (map? node)
         (= :var (:op node))
         (= sym (symbol (:var node))))))

; ---

(->> '(->>
       [{:a 1}]
       (map (fn [map]
              (update map :a vector)))
       (mapcat (partial (comp (partial map inc) :a))))

     (ana/analyze)
     (ana-tree-seq)
     (filter (ana-var=-fn 'clojure.core/map))
     (count))
; ⇒ 2
```